# Facebook Open Graph Story- caption and app link with user generated photo

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, applinks

I am trying to publish an open graph story containing an App Link.

I set up my story with the following code-

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{ 
    @"og:type": @"bcskitracker:tour",     
    @"og:title": tour.route.name,
    @"og:distance": [tour.distance stringValue],
    @"og:vertical": [tour.ascent stringValue],
    @"og:description": @"description",
    @"og:url": @"https://fb.me/786890254772699",
    @"og:image": photo
};
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *tourObject = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"bcskitracker:ski";
[action setObject:tourObject forKey:@"bcskitracker:tour"];
[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"bcskitracker:tour";
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

If the photo is marked as userGenerated:NO, the story is published as expected with a caption and if you tap the post it opens the iPhone app:

[image]

However only one photo can be displayed and appears very small on the iPhone.  If I mark the photo as userGenerated:YES the post displays the large photo, however there is no caption and no app link (only a link to facebook's app directory)-

[image]

The post doesn't even display the tour title as constructed in the story template- 
[image]

Is there any way to include the caption and app link with a user generated photo?  I understand I can set the action.message but this is restricted and doesn't link to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently intended behaviour; if you set a photo attachment as `user_generated = yes`, it's considered as a photo upload. In that case, you can't mix in Open Graph information. So it's one of the two :)

What you could do, is to generate a **single** image on your server side with **both** the map and uploaded photo. If you use that as your `og:image`, it will be included in the post.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected.  I did try experimenting with a composite photo as you suggested but the image was so small on the iPhone that it looked terrible.  Hopefully facebook will allow for more flexibility in the future.